# How can I view script function value in html block in Angular application?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

*I want to show "timeStops" value in html block from the script.*

"timeStops" is output as array and I want to show this array value in html block.

**Output of timeStops:**

[
"21:00",
"21:30",
"22:00",
"22:30",
"23:00",
"23:30",
"00:00",
"00:30",
"01:00",
"01:30",
"02:00",
"02:30",
"03:00",
"03:30",
"04:00",
"04:30"
]

**My Code:**

```
<script>
  function getTimeStops(start, end) {
      var startTime = moment(start, 'HH:mm');
      var endTime = moment(end, 'HH:mm');

      if (endTime.isBefore(startTime)) {
        endTime.add(1, 'day');
      }

      var timeStops = [];

      while (startTime <= endTime) {
        timeStops.push(new moment(startTime).format('HH:mm'));
        startTime.add(15, 'minutes');
      }
      return timeStops;
    }

    var timeStops = getTimeStops('11:00', '02:00');
    console.log('timeStops ', timeStops);
    timeStops = getTimeStops('11:00', '23:59'); //Want to show this timeStops in html block
    console.log('timeStops ', timeStops);
</script>


<div>
  <p>I want to show "timeStops" value here from above script</p>
</div>
```

Comment: which version of angular do you want to use ?

Comment: Angular CLI: 11.2.4
Node: 14.15.4

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1102.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         11.2.4 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   11.2.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          11.2.4 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.1102.4 (cli-only)

Comment: write your logic in page compoment and in html just write like `<div>{{timeStops | json}}</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update `app.component.ts` like

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from "moment";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  getTimeStops(start: any, end: any) {
    var startTime = moment(start, 'HH:mm');
    var endTime = moment(end, 'HH:mm');

    if (endTime.isBefore(startTime)) {
      endTime.add(1, 'day');
    }

    var timeStops = [];

    while (startTime <= endTime) {
      timeStops.push(moment(startTime).format('HH:mm'));
      startTime.add(15, 'minutes');
    }
    return timeStops;
  }
  timeStops = this.getTimeStops('11:00', '02:00')
}
```

And your add this line in your `app.component.html`

`*ngFor` loop will display values individually

```
<div>{{timeStops | json}}</div>

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let time of timeStops; let index = index">{{ time }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's give me an error:

<div>
      {{timeStops | json}}
      <p>I want to show "timeStops" value here from above script</p>
</div>

Error is:
Identifier 'timeStops' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member ng

Comment: I have updated answer please check now, I write in Angular letest version.

Comment: I got the output like this:

[ "11:00", "11:15", "11:30", "11:45", "12:00", "12:15", "12:30", "12:45", "13:00", "13:15", "13:30", "13:45", "14:00", "14:15", "14:30", "14:45", "15:00", "15:15", "15:30", "15:45", "16:00", "16:15", "16:30", "16:45", "17:00", "17:15", "17:30", "17:45", "18:00", "18:15", "18:30", "18:45", "19:00", "19:15", "19:30", "19:45", "20:00", "20:15", "20:30", "20:45", "21:00", "21:15", "21:30", "21:45", "22:00", "22:15", "22:30", "22:45", "23:00", "23:15", "23:30" ]

how can I get the individual value of this output. I want to separate every data.

Please help me!